# Active Record Destroy ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, schema

I am trying to destroy a Purchase object like this

```
def destroy
        @purchase=current_user.purchases.where(flooding_property_id: params[:id])
        @purchase.destroy(flooding_property_id: params[:id])
    end
```

I know the error is because of some sort of association I have, but I can't seem to figure it out. My model is as follows

```
class FloodingProperty < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :purchases 
    has_many :users, through: :purchases
end
```

Purchase Model

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :flooding_property
end
```

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :purchases
  has_many :carts
  has_many :flooding_properties, through: :purchases
end
```

Database schema:

```
create_table "flooding_properties", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string    "address"
    t.string    "zipcode"
    t.geography "latlon",       limit: {:srid=>4326, :type=>"point", :geographic=>true}
    t.datetime  "last_updated"
    t.datetime  "created_at",                                                            null: false
    t.datetime  "updated_at",                                                            null: false
  end

  add_index "flooding_properties", ["latlon"], name: "index_flooding_properties_on_latlon", using: :gist
  add_index "flooding_properties", ["zipcode"], name: "index_flooding_properties_on_zipcode", using: :btree

  create_table "purchases", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.boolean  "billed",               default: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "flooding_property_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                           null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                           null: false
  end

  add_index "purchases", ["billed"], name: "index_purchases_on_billed", where: "(billed = false)", using: :btree
  add_index "purchases", ["flooding_property_id"], name: "index_purchases_on_flooding_property_id", using: :btree
  add_index "purchases", ["user_id"], name: "index_purchases_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call #destroy on a single instance. This is not a problem of your associations.

```
def destroy
  current_user
    .purchases
    .find_by(flooding_property_id: params[:id])
    .destroy
end
```

I am using .find_by instead of .where because .where returns multiple matches. .find_by always returns the first one it finds.

If you indeed want to destroy all matches you can use .where and .destroy_all:

```
def destroy
  current_user
    .purchases
    .where(flooding_property_id: params[:id])
    .destroy_all
end
```

Comment: Wow, that solves it. Thank you so much! I originally thought that was a problem but I tried @purchase.first.destroy(flooding_property_id: params[:id]) but that didn't work.